# Does Mojang occasionally invalidate all current game sessions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does Mojang occasionally invalidate all sessions, making it so everyone has to restart Minecraft?

I've been playing Minecraft for a few years. I know if you log in with another instance of Minecraft, your session will be invalidated. However, when joining a new server after a few hours, I will occasionally have to restart Minecraft after being kicked for the "Invalid Session: Try restarting your game" without actually having logged in on a separate instance.

It's happened a couple times in the last few months, but nothing else suspicious is going on.

Comment: I can confirm that this has occasionally happened to me.  Do you use a mojang account (log in with an email), or are you using a classic (beta) account (log in with your username)?

Comment: I play Premium minecraft and have had my account for years. The session invalidating was never a problem until later this year. I recently (a couple months ago) migrated my account to the Mojang account system.

Comment: I've had the same issue happen to me as I said.  But in my case I use a beta account.  Still don't know why this happens then.  EDIT: What servers do you play on?  Is it a server that has one main hub world where you go to sub-worlds?

Comment: Yes, I usually play on the large servers such as Mineplex or the Hive, which all use different servers to host their games, but I only get an invalid session ID error when actually disconnecting and reconnecting to the server. It doesn't only happen on large server's though, I sometimes also get the error when joining my private server after playing for a couple hours straight.

Answer (score 1):

If a new session, or your current session is interrupted, you will have to re-authenticate with the login server

Answer (score 1):

Invalid Session happens when another instance of Minecraft is launched with the same login, it detects that there are two Minecraft instances running on the same username, and wants you to revalidate it to make sure its YOU. This also happens if you change your IP or change your VPN during gameplay